# Loading a page to the previous scroll point

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page that generates a long table of items.  One column lists actions available for each item (row) one of which is "delete." After deleting the record the entire page is reloaded, with the top of the table at the top of the screen.    This is a bother, though.  If I'm deleting an item far down in the table I want the reload to scroll to where I was, so it's easy to delete the next item.  As it is, I have to manually scroll down several times and find where I was before I can delete the next row.

How can I make a new load of the page scroll automatically down to where I was?

I'm doing this in WordPress, if it makes any difference.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: You may want to consider assigning anchors (`<a>`) with a generated ID based on the `loop` used to output the table data. From here you could store the ID being deleted and when the page is redirected you would redirect it to the previous or next numbered `<a>` tag. Consideration has to be taken for the first and last records depending on the methodology used.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I did this for a previous job was to get the index of the "tr" that housed the delete button and store it into session storage. On  the page reload I got the index number out of session storage and scrolled to that index.

```
//function to set line index on clicking a table row        
    $("table").eq(2).on('click','tr',function () 
        {
            var lineNum = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            sessionStorage.setItem('lineNumber',lineNum);
        });

    //retrieves line index and scrolls to it
    var line_Number=parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('lineNumber'));
    $("tr").eq(line_Number)[0].scrollIntoView();
```

If I was doing it now, I would probably use Ajax and forget about reloading the page and simply delete the contents and leave the page where it was without having to worry about the index or scrolling to it.

Comment: @Steve -yeah I didn't know about Ajax when I did that - gotta say it worked a treat though. Now I would just have a separate php page that handled the form elements and altered the database and the page couyld stay where it was at the time of the user's interaction. Incidentally - I have done it this way as well and have had a common "delete(value)" function where value is the id of the delete button that had been pressed (and therefore gave me the id of the row I had to delete. That way - its only one function that can handle all delete buttons in the page - irrespective of the data present.

Comment: [Belongs before the previous comment.] @gavgif I like the idea of using Ajax.  If I do a jQuery  .load into the table I can pass a parameter that tells the page to just generate the table data, Or perhaps I could do the .load into document and let the whole page reproduce.  But would that reproduce without changing the scroll position? If I deleted record 110, e.g., and then let .load bring the entire page into document would record 111 be in  the center of my screen or would I be at the top of the table?  Thanks for your input

Comment: hard to say without seeing code, but my guess is that it would reload the whole page structure and you would lose your position again. The way i did it was to simply remove the row from the table (I used either remove() or even just .hide() to remove it from view and had a php page that deleted the content from the db - so therefore the page was really just the display (and the contents simply removed from view) and the db got updated in the background and the next time it was loaded showed the amended structure.